# post-up rule not setting eee off post reboot

Tags: networking, 22.04, raspberrypi

I have a raspberry pi 4, with 22.04 installed. I keep getting drop outs from the network with errors in dmseg like

```
bcmgenet_xmit: tx ring 1 full when queue 2 awake
```

Another post suggested that this may be due to the EEE setting being on for the eth0. While I can set it off using

```
sudo ethtool --set-eee eth0 eee off
```

This doesn't persist over reboots.

I've tried adding this to /etc/network/interfaces

```
# Ethernet
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    post-up /sbin/ethtool --set-eee eth0 eee off
address 192.168.1.3
```

But this doesn't seem to work and EEE is set on after a reboot. What is wrong with my configuration? How can I debug this?

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` is not used in 22.04.

Comment: Well that explains it :-) Suggestions for how I can achieve the same result?