# How to configure Energy Efficient Ethernet (EEE) permanently off using netplan?

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, netplan

I have a raspberry pi 4, with 22.04 installed. I keep getting drop outs from the network with errors in dmseg like

```
bcmgenet_xmit: tx ring 1 full when queue 2 awake
```

Another post suggested that this may be due to the EEE setting being on for the eth0. While I can set it off using

```
sudo ethtool --set-eee eth0 eee off
```

However, this doesn't persist over reboots.

How do I do this using netplan?

Comment: You already asked this in an earlier question today. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435380/post-up-rule-not-setting-eee-off-post-reboot

Answer (score 0):

Netplan does not expose ethtool options through its schema.  However, you could implement this either using a `udev` rule (run before the interface is brought up as soon as the hardware is detected), or a `networkd-dispatcher` script (run after the interface has been configured by `netplan`).  Some ethtool options on some hardware cannot be configured while the interface is in "up" state, but if this one can, I recommend a `networkd-dispatcher` script as this is a simple shell script.